# Spring Security How to encrypt an incoming password in SHA256 + salt and compare the result with the encrypted password in the database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My clients use Basic auth for authentication. I store their passwords in this form - SHA256 (cleartext_password + salt), the "salt" value is stored in a separate column in the database for each user. Clients send their password to the controller in cleartext.

That means,  the password should be checked as follows: I extract the cleartext_password from the BasicAuth header, I get the salt value for this user from the database and execute such conversion - SHA256 (cleartext_password + salt), then I check that the resulting string and the string stored in the database matched. The question is, how to convert the incoming password (BasicAuth) into the form -  SHA256 (cleartext_password + salt), before Spring Security compares the incoming password with the  password returned by UserDetailsService (password from the database)?

Here is my current SecurityConfig and CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder());
    }

}


@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
        if (user != null){
            return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.
                    User.withUsername(username)
                    .password(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't/shouldn't. What you should do is implement a custom `PasswordEncoder` that implements the logic you need. Also your code is flawed as you are encoding an encoding password so now it will simply never match and you should throw a `UserNotFoundException` not an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Did you manage to do it?